# Insert image in database as blob type - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to store the image as blob type in database using codeigniter. I don't want to upload the image in a folder. I just wanted to store the image in db as  blob.

I have this in my model

```
 public function insert_user()
 {    
    $get_image = $this->input->post(file_get_contents($_FILES['imgProfile']['tmp_name']));  //imgProfile is the name of the image tag  
    $insert_values = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('FirstName'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('LastName'),
            'profile_image' => $this->$get_image 
            );  

    $insert_qry = $this->db->insert('user', $insert_values);    
    }
```

My controller contains

```
public function new_user()
{
        $this->user_model->insert_user(); //user_model is the model name
}
```

**Error:**

```
Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\CI\system\core\Model.php on line 52
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is L52 in Model.php?

Comment: reference $this->$getimage is wrong it should be $this->getimage or simple $getimage (incase its local as in the function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your code you have typo related to variable. It seems you might be calling your `variable` as `function`.

Even though if you want to access the value from a function then it should be written as **$this->get_image()** and for variables **$this->get_image** not as **$this->$get_image**

```
public function insert_user()
 {    
    $get_image = $this->input->post(file_get_contents($_FILES['imgProfile']['tmp_name']));  //imgProfile is the name of the image tag  
    $insert_values = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('FirstName'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('LastName'),
            'profile_image' => $get_image //its a variable
            );  

    $insert_qry = $this->db->insert('user', $insert_values);    
    }
```