# crud operation with datatables using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

so here i got datatables serverside processing with codeigniter,and it's working,but,the problem is that i want to **add some image** that displayed from database with **longblob** format,so that i can add crud operation on that image too.

the part of display image from database is done,but the rest of it (delete,insert,update) is still not working,here is the piece of code to display image :

```
   public function list()
{
    $list = $this->person->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $person) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $person->Nama;
        //add html for action
        $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_person('."'".$person->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_person('."'".$person->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';
        $row[] = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($person->image).'" height="60" width="75" class="img-thumbnail" />';
        $data[] = $row;
    }

}
```

that's all i can provide,the ajax datatype is JSON,so what i have to do in clientside so that the input file type can be transfer to serverside code so that can be inserted ?

Comment: you should send image in form data from client side and save in some folder in server side

Comment: to do that you should first convert base64 image to blob and send it by putting it on form data on a client side

Comment: So first i have input file then after that send to serverside and save in some folder,but then how to insert that to database?

Comment: you only insert filename in database i.e. imagename (name of image stored in folder and stored in database should be same)

Comment: How to turn the file that being send to serverside into data that can be saved as blob format? It's that can even work?

Comment: But what i want is to save data as blob,not text formated,if i do that than my file will be so much bigger

Comment: see this https://www.cloudways.com/blog/codeigniter-upload-file-image/ how to upload image in codeingiter

Comment: see this it may give you some idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823651/insert-image-in-database-as-blob-type-codeigniter but i would not recommend you to store image in blob type

Comment: Don't store images in your database as a blob.  What if in the future you want to serve the images from a Content Delivery Network?  Or if you want to do some optimisation on them to compress them further?  Do yourself a favor and store them in the file system (that's what a file system is for after all) and just store their filename, location and any meta data in your database