# How to store image byte array in php codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, base64

I am using `PHP` `Codeigniter`, I want to decode a `base64` string into the image from the front end, they will pass an only `base64` array.

After getting that I want to decode `BASE64` to an image and store into a folder. Before I didn't work with base64 encoding/decoding. Somebody, please help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: Do you mean a blob? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823651/insert-image-in-database-as-blob-type-codeigniter

Comment: @Alex No, am working in back end and  from front end they will send only BASE64 encoded data. I want to decode that data and store image into a folder.

Comment: You mean you will recieve something like `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/7`... You really need to post examples of what you will receive.